# Trouble CHMODing a file (777)

Tags: centos, vps, chmod

In order to CHMOD 777 a file, am I using the command correctly?

`chmod 777 /var/www/html/core/database/connect.php`

I am trying to use it, but it isn't saying anything... like no error or not saying that is was a success.

Just so you know, I am on a VPS with CentOS 6 (64 bit).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's not suppose to say anything it's *NIX (it only tells you when something went wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command appears correct.  Many unix utilities only provide feedback in the event of a failure.  To be sure that the command worked or not you can check that the exit status is 0 or use ls to see what the file permissions are now.

For the first way, you can check the status a couple ways.

- `chmod 777 /var/www/html/core/database/connect.php ; echo $?`
- `chmod 777 /var/www/html/core/database/connect.php && echo 'it worked'`

To check the file permissions, just run `ls -l /var/www/html/core/database/connect.php`

Please remember though that with 777 permissions any user can read, change, and excecute the file.